vuejs @input is getting called only after onfocusout, i want to call it when user is typing
i am trying to use @input on input field in vuejs, but the function assigned to it gets called only after user has stopped typing and the focus is out of the input field, that means it is getting called on onFocusout, what i want is, when user is typing, at that time i need to call the function.
Below is my code:
<input
    v-model="inputValue"
    type="text"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :class="['w-full !border-none !focus:border-none p-2.5 shadow-none', disabled ? 'text-[#969c9f]' : 'black']"
    @input="ValidateInput"
    :disabled="disabled"
/>


ValidateInput(){
    if(this.inputValue){
        if(this.valueType == "Number"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        }else if(this.valueType == "SP"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/\D/g, '');
        }else if(this.valueType == "Number_with_TS"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
        }else if(this.valueType == "SP_with_TS"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/\D/g, '');
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
        }else if(this.valueType == "decimal"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
            const parts = this.inputValue.split('.');
            if (parts.length > 2) {
                this.inputValue = parts[0] + '.' + parts.slice(1).join('');
            }
        }else if(this.valueType=="ZipCode"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            if (this.inputValue.length > 4) {
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substring(0, 4);
            }
        } else if (this.valueType === "disabled") {
            this.inputValue = 0;
            this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue);
        } else if(this.valueType == "model_spec"){
            if (this.inputValue.length > 60) {
                this.inputValue = this.inputValue.substring(0, 60);
            }
        }else if(this.valueType=="cylinder_volume"){
            this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '');
        }

        if(this.inputValue == ""){
            this.inputValue=null;
        }
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.inputValue);
    }
}

I am new to vuejs, can someone tell, how to solve this ?
I have tried several methods but none of that worked.

It works on user input as well, can you create a reproducible example?

Minimal reproduce on vue 3.3 in composition API, validation fires on every input.
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from "vue";

const input = ref<string>("");

const validate = () => {
    console.log("Validating input");
};
</script>

<template>
    <input
        v-model="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type something"
        @input="validate"
    >
</template>

